# Some keys on my keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I am using Lenovo IdeaPad Z560. The keys 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, F10, F11, F12 are not working. The ones below the function keys, that is. I used numpad to type this question. What could be the possible reason? How do I solve this? This is going to be a big problem. Please help.

Edit: In the following image, I have marked the non-functioning keys with red rectangles.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have ruled out software problems (e.g. by booting to a Linux LiveCD or similar), this seems like a manufacturing defect with the keyboard (assuming your cat hasn't tried to eat it, you haven't spilled orange juice or acid on it, or a different situation doesn't apply that would directly cause failure).

EDIT: It may be worth trying to re-seat the ribbon cable underneath the keyboard. This is roughly equivalent to removing and replacing it; read on.

If it is under warranty I would recommend contacting Lenovo and applying the normal phone techniques to get it replaced promptly. If not, a replacement keyboard is usually inexpensive online and is easy to install with the help of a screwdriver and the [maintenance manual](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=UM013268) (FRU 1100 on pages 47, 48).

Comment: You seem to have jumped to that conclusion hastily

Comment: My conclusion is based on assumptions that you didn't satisfy when you composed the question--my "conclusion" is more of a "flowchart to what I believe is the answer". For example--did you try your keyboard in another OS (or in the BIOS) yet? :)

Comment: I didn't ask the question... I just think it's hasty to immediately say it's bad if one can't "rule out software problems."

Comment: @Garrett--sorry, thought you were the OP. Please interpret my response as if I didn't make that mistake.

Comment: I have a dual-boot system, and I have already ruled out software problems. I don't have a cat. I didn't spill orange juice or acid \[but I can't vouch for kids in the house]. Warranty period is over. Thanks for the information about replacement keyboard. I'll first try to get in touch with some laptop technician, and then go for this solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Garrett - re-read the grammatical mechanics I employed... If it works in a different OS, my answer is out the window. :)

Comment: @missingfaktor - this keyboard is roughly $30 on a popular auction website. Keep this in mind when talking to any technician who may be interested in selling you a service.

Comment: @Alex Hirzel I see quite clearly what you're saying and franky it is possible to still not work in another OS and *NOT* be a keyboard failure.

Comment: Garrett, how so?

Comment: Garrett is right. I have once had a motherboard fault which made the entire system useless because it kept repeating a single keystroke forever the moment I turn on the computer. What you're experiencing _could_ also be motherboard fault. You will find out when you replace the internal keyboard with an exact spare and it _doesn't_ solve the problem, then it's the keyboard controller's problem (or generally, motherboard fault). (Assuming you know it's not OS problem).

Comment: In this specific case my gut feeling is simply that the keyboard is at fault. Laptop keyboard PCBs and ribbon cables are flimsy and a single broken wire could eradicate a whole swath of scan codes which could be mapped seemingly randomly across the keyboard. Regardless--having already eliminated stuck shifts, software settings and establishing that the behavior is consistent, I fail to see the fault in a line of reasoning that implicates hardware fault (be it keyboard controller or keyboard, a fine distinction at this stage because the only constructive action is to throw a keyboard at it).

Answer (score 1):

Many keyboards have an alternate key function that unlike the typical Fn "function" keys, who are only activated by depressing the Fn key and the desired key simultaneously, are toggled on an off by a separate key, much like the CAPS LOCK key. Not being personally familiar with your specific laptop model, I would search for such a key somewhere on your keyboard. Typically the extra functions are labeled in a different color and the special function key will be colored to match.

Finally, I have seen particular areas of keyboards on laptops cease functioning due to high temperatures/overheating. Check your temperatures and compare them to what is considered normal for your model. The surface of the keyboard should also not be hot (or even too warm) to the touch.

Comment: Please read my question properly. Numpad is working, which is what I used for typing numbers in the question. Shift, Fn, Ctrl, Caps Lock - all combinations have been tried \[I think].